# Getting additional data in firebase/auth - onAuthStateChanged

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get extra data from a users collection in firestore when user loggs in. I do this in a useEffect function in a AuthContext. This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      const fetchUserData = async () => {
        if (!user) {
          setCurrentUser(null);
          setLoading(false);
          return;
        }
        const userData = await fetchUserDataFromFirestore(user.uid);
        setCurrentUser({ ...user, ...userData });
        setLoading(false);
      };

      fetchUserData();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [currentUser]);
```

This kind of works as I do get the data but messages are piling up in the console as can be seen in my screenshot:

[image]

The fetchUserDataFromFirestore function is implemented like this:

```
export const fetchUserDataFromFirestore = async (id) => {
  const docRef = doc(db, "users", id);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists) {
    const userData = docSnap.data();
    return userData;
  }
  return null;
};
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: `docSnap.exists()` is a method returning boolean.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference this is how I did it

```
const [uid, setUid] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUid(user.uid)
    } else {
      setUid(null)
    }
  })

  return () => {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}, [])

// set currentUser state
useEffect(() => {
  if (uid) {
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid)

    getDoc(userRef)
      .then((docSnapshot) => {
        const data = docSnapshot.data()
        setCurrentUser(data)
      })
  }
}, [uid])
```

Comment: And this is how pros do it: `onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), user => user ? setUid(user.uid) : setUid(null) )`

Comment: Agreed. Had some extra logic which I deleted to answer this post but for this case your example makes more sense.